# Multi-value conditional parameters in Where clause - SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I know how to create compound conditional filters (see below example) where, depending on the one value in the parameter, the corresponding where statement will be applied (example below).  However, how could I make the below example multi-value parameter i.e. the user doesn't have to select just one option but can choose which option (or options) to select. I'm using SSRS Report Builder and SQL Server 2016.  Thank you.
**EDIT:  here is a better example from another Question on StackOverflow:**

```
FROM yourProductsTable p
WHERE 
--Apply the "type" filters
(
    (
        @TypeParam = 'All' --then include both Items and Accessories
        AND p.ProductType in ('I','A')
    )
    OR 
    (
        @TypeParam = 'A' --Accessories only
        AND p.ProductType = 'A'
    )
    OR
    (
        @TypeParam = 'I' --Items only
        AND p.ProductType = 'I'
    )
    OR
    (
        @TypeParam = 'E' --Items only, but Exclude Category A and Product D
        AND p.ProductType = 'I'
        AND p.Category <> 'A'
        AND p.Product <> 'D'
    )
)
--Apply Other filters: i.e. category
AND p.Category in (@SSRSCategoryMultiSelectParam)
```

Comment: In SSRS, if you are using multi-value parameters and an inline statement then you would use the format `WHERE Column IN (@Parameter)` and SSRS will (safely?) inject the values. If you are using a Procedure, then SSRS passes a delimited string, and you will need to use a string splitter.

Comment: Thanks Larnu I know about in line statements but I can't use it in this context.  Please see example.  If parameter has more than one value, then none of the condition will be selected...I want to use parameter value(s) in the WHERE Clause conditionally...

Comment: Everything in your query is `=`, that's why, @ZigL. `= {Multi Value Parameter}` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Larnu this is not a very good example I have created.  Sorry!  The reason I can't use in line statement is because in my actual query, I'm pre selecting multiple options in the conditions.

Comment: Sorry, that was embarrassing!  I have updated with a better example!

Comment: Again, those are `=` operators. Use `IN`. `'E' IN (@TypeParam) AND p.ProductType = 'I'`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming yu are doing this directly in the SSRS dataset (not in a stored proc) AND your parameter **values** as 'All', 'A', 'I' and 'E' then

You should be able to change this...

```
    @TypeParam = 'A' --Accessories only
    AND p.ProductType = 'A'
```

to this

```
    'A' IN (@TypeParam) --Accessories only
    AND p.ProductType = 'A'
```

repeat for all instances and that should give you what you want.